# replace the compiler in boost build v2

Tags: c++, boost, build, boost-build, bjam

I would like to hook a compiler tool in the boost build.

Note that I do not want to replace the compiler, that is easy:

```
using msvc : : : <compiler>mycompiler ;
```

What I am looking for is my tool to be literally placed in front of the execution line. Something similar to the unit-test launcher option.

```
using msvc : : : <compiler-launcher>launcher ;
```

to result in

```
launcher <the original line here>
```

Ideas how I can do that hopefully without need to change the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this there is currently no support for this, so you are stuck with the `<compiler>` option. I can think of two possible ways to accomplish this:

1. Try setting the compiler to `<compiler>"launcher cl"` or
2. Create a batch file which would create the appropriate command line
   and then use it as a `<compiler>cl_wrapper.bat`

   That batch file could look something like this:

   **cl_wrapper.bat**

   @launcher cl.exe %*

Comment: This will do it. My concern for this approach is that it overrides the default logic of determining the compiler and I might finish with overriding the expected compiler with cl ... but if there is no better way this will do it.

Comment: I think all msvc compilers are named cl, so this should not pose an issue, as long as Boost.Build invokes the correct setup script.